# PHP SQL i another SQL query

Tags: php, sql

Description:

```
table1 - columns: f1,f2,f3,f4,f5
```

in these columns I have `rom_number` for temperature sensors

```
table2 - columns: act_temperature, rom_number
```

I need `act_temperature` from `table2` for each `rom_number` stored in `table1` (cols `f1`,`f2`,...)

I have code:

```
// main loop
$rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tabela1 WHERE active='on' ");
$row = $rows->fetchAll();
    foreach ($row as $a) {

            $f1 = $a['f1'];
            $f2 = $a['f2'];
            $f3 = $a['f3'];
            $f4 = $a['f4'];
            $f5 = $a['f5'];
    }
```

How to change the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [`LEFT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) on table 2 for each columns `f1`,`f2`,...

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.*,
        t2_1.act_temperature as tmp1,
        t2_2.act_temperature as tmp2,
        t2_3.act_temperature as tmp3,
        t2_4.act_temperature as tmp4,
        t2_5.act_temperature as tmp4
 FROM tabela1 t1
 LEFT JOIN tabela2 t2_1 ON t2_1.rom_number = t1.f1
 LEFT JOIN tabela2 t2_2 ON t2_2.rom_number = t1.f2
 LEFT JOIN tabela2 t2_3 ON t2_3.rom_number = t1.f3
 LEFT JOIN tabela2 t2_4 ON t2_4.rom_number = t1.f4
 LEFT JOIN tabela2 t2_5 ON t2_5.rom_number = t1.f5
 WHERE active='on' ";
```

Then, `$a` should have following keys : `f1`,`f2`,...,`f5`,`tmp1`,`tmp2`,...,`tmp5`.